# Kotlin Kotest Tests with Mocked Classes Failing Randomly with "no answer found"

Tags: kotlin, mockk, kotest

I've got a unit test using Kotest and Mockk:

```kotlin
package application

import io.kotest.core.spec.style.FunSpec
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.mockk
import io.mockk.verify
import org.threeten.extra.Days
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.PutObjectResponse
import application.TimeFixture.anInstant
import application.contract.ContractIdFixture.aContractId
import application.contract.ContractStatusFixture.aContractStatus
import application.contract.aws.ContractStatusDdbRepository
import application.commons.aws.S3ClientImpl as S3Client
import java.time.Instant

class ContractServiceTest : FunSpec({
    test("test") {
        // Given
        val s3Client = mockk<S3Client>()
        val status = mockk<ContractStatusDdbRepository>()
        val underTest = ContractService(repository, s3Client)
        val contract = aContractStatus()
        every { status.getAll() } returns listOf(contract)
        every { s3Client.putObject(any(), any()) } returns mockk<PutObjectResponse>()

        // When
        val res = underTest.exportAllContracts()

        // Then
        res.total shouldBe 1
        val capturedData = mutableListOf<ByteArray>()
        verify(exactly = 1) { status.getAll() }
        verify(exactly = 2) { s3Client.putObject(any<String>(), any<String>()) }
        // ... rest of the test
    }
})
```

And it passes when running individually. But when I run the whole test suite, it keeps failing with a consistent error message "no answer found", sometimes for `repository.getAll` call or `s3Client.putObject` call:

```
no answer found for S3ClientImpl(#1).putObject(myBucket, contracts-2023-12-20.csv) among the configured answers: ()
io.mockk.MockKException: no answer found for S3ClientImpl(#1).putObject(myBucket, contracts.csv) among the configured answers: ()
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.defaultAnswer(MockKStub.kt:91)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:270)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:24)
    at app//io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:21)
    at app//application.commons.aws.S3ClientImpl.putObject(S3Client.kt:15)
```

As can be seen in the code, I moved everything inside the test method to isolate it from the rest of the test suite. I also use `any` matcher to match anything, just in case. But it keeps failing.
Is there something I'm missing with respect to the internal of Mockk and/or Kotest?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to mock it differently - to return real object?

Comment: I can do that. But at least the first mocked object; the repository is mocked with a real object.

Comment: Tried with a simple integer value as the return value. Same. still fails :(

Comment: try changing the isolation mode of your test suite

Comment: I tried, no success :(

Comment: I see you import `application.commons.aws.S3ClientImpl as S3Client`.  Try using the interface itself: `software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client`... my hunch is that implementation class might have some state that interferes with the mocking.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/q/77870426/1847378 where OP found that creating Mocks in a Companion object similarly produced randon "No Answer" when running a whole suite together