# Kotlin MockK declaring mocks in companion objects

Tags: kotlin, unit-testing, mockk

I was writing some unit tests in MockK and had a lot of test cases while also sharing some mock variables between tests, so I thought I could declare the mocks in the companion object to not clutter the tests.

Example assuming I used 'mockObject' a lot and the tested class returns 'mockObject':

```
companion object {
    val mockObject = mockk<TestClass> {
       every { property } returns "test"
    }
}
```

When I ran each test, it passed. However, when I ran the test suite all at once, various tests started failing and saying 'No answer for TestClass.property', even though I had `clearAllMocks()` done after each test. After a lot of headache, I finally figured out that moving the mock out of the companion object and putting it directly in the test fixed my issues. I was wondering why this is the case.

Comment: can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show both the non-working and the working cases?

Comment: Possibly related to unresolved Question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77690510/1847378